# GetForegroundWindows (and an other Form too...)

Tags: delphi

I have two Forms (Form1, Form2) the second is a smaller shaped one and it is above the first, and I would like a screenshot not only from the 'Active' or 'Foreground' window but from both... Of course, only from these 2 forms and not from the full Desktop... How can I change this code to do it? Thanks.

```
    hWin := GetForegroundWindow;


  if FullWindow then
  begin
    GetWindowRect(hWin,r);
    dc := GetWindowDC(hWin) ;
  end else
  begin
    Windows.GetClientRect(hWin, r);
    dc := GetDC(hWin) ;
  end;

  w := (r.Right - r.Left)+ 1;
  h := (r.Bottom) - (r.Top);


  bmp := TBitmap.Create;
  bmp.Height := h;
  bmp.Width := w;
   BitBlt(bmp.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, w, h, DC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
```

Comment: Does not work this way. You have to take **2** snapshots and draw top window's snapshot over bottom's.

Comment: @TLama Why do you need to consider monitors? Can't you screenshot the forms without considering which monitor they are on?

Comment: @David, well, after re-reading the question I see your point. I got this question as that OP wants to take one screenshot of two forms exactly as they are displayed (overlayed in their Z order), but I'm obviously wrong. Taking back all my comments. [and deleting all of them including this one...]

Comment: @TLama No, I think you got it right. But you can achieve that by capturing the forms and blitting them onto a bitmap large enough to contain both rectangles.